# Python false detect from antiviruses

Tags: python, antivirus

I built my python application using pyinstaller like 4 months ago, and all was right.
After these months my application started to be detect from some antiviruses: AVAST, AVG, Kaspersky,COMODO and others..

I didn't understand why, so i tryed to write a python script that just print and sleep, then i converted
it using pyinstaller, and i got the same detection rate.

This is very ridicolous for antiviruses companies.

Then i tryed to don't use --windowed option when building the exe with pyinstaller (this means that when you run the exe the console doesn't appaer if activated)
And POOF the application is not detected...

Could someone explain why now is detected using the same script and the same option to build?

Also how could i solve this issue considering i can't give my software if seems malicious and i also can't give a software that opens a console while running..

Thank you.

Comment: Consider scanning your computer for viruses.

Comment: Sir did you understood what i wrote?

Comment: I did.  I'm speculating that your pyinstaller is corrupt, or perhaps something else on your machine related to your development toolchain.  Otherwise, you're asserting that any program written under pyinstaller is detected as a virus, which doesn't seem likely.

Comment: You might also want to check and see if pyinstaller has released an update.

Comment: you could just have your scripts and all in a folder and have that folder marked as excluded in the antivirus settings.

Comment: This is a very common issue with PyInstaller, and the "antiviruses companies" are not at fault. Many amateur viruses are written in Python and then made portable using PyInstaller. Since all these portable executables contain the same bootloader by default, PyInstaller's default bootloader is flagged by anti-virus software (since it's a common fragment that is shared among many real malicious softwares). The only real solution is to make your own bootloader, which is not trivial.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but what do you mean to make my own bootloader?